# value selector in json in dataweave

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

I'm doing json to xml in dataweave and for this m using variable, this is my below json

```
{"step1": [
"lightratio": {
   "step1Name": "mystep"

 },

 "lightratio": {
  "step1Name":"mystep"


  }
  ]

  }
```

my dataweave script

```
  %dw 1.0
  %output application/xml 
  %var test = step1.lightratio.step1Name
   --- 
  {
   my logic
   }
```

Myquery:- I want to assigned the value of json element "step1Name"  i.e "mystep" to dataweave variable i.e "test" ( onlye value) , how can I achieve this , it is fine for me if i put only value which is position at zero in json array.

Answer (score 1):

i assume the json from your question is the payload. you access `step1Name` from the first element in the `step1` list like this:

```
payload.step1[0].lightratio.step1Name
```

Comment: yes this is my payload and in case if my payload is null means no json payload is coming in that case how u add null check. because this expression   "payload.step1[0].lightratio.step1Name"  will failed as there no value present at [0]..

Please advice

Comment: dataweave has a feature called [reader configuration](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/6/using-dataweave-in-studio#reader-configuration). There you can tell dataweave how to handle null situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skipNullOn` for situations when payload is null.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
%var payload = {  
   "step1":[  
      {  
         "lightratio":{  
            "step1Name":"mystep"
         }
      },
      {  
         "lightratio":{  
            "step1Name":"mystep"
             }
          }
       ]
    }
%var test = payload.step1[0].lightratio.step1Name
---
root : {
    varValue: test
}
```

Output with payload

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<root>
  <varValue>mystep</varValue>
</root>
```

Output with null payload

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<root/>
```